# How to return only the max row from a table in a left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which contains information on cars `dbo.Car`

```
CarID | Make      | Model
23      Volvo       XC90
40      Chevrolet   Camaro
46      BMW         Z4
```

There's another table, `dbo.CIS` which lists additional information. Its something like this:

```
CarID | Dist | U1 | U2 | U3 | U4 | U5 -- U22
23      180    65   94   80   56   88    71
23      1170   68   93   24   23   19    93
40      908    89   15   68   46   59    31
46      500    10   20   30   40   50    35
46      2300   60   62   44   52   75    99
```

What the data means in this other table doesn't matter too much. But I want to join on `CarID` and only return 1 row that has the highest value in the `Dist` column from the `dbo.CIS` table when the CarID appears more than once in that table.

So for CarID 23 I want to return this:

```
CarID | Make   | Model | CarID | Dist | U1 | U2 | U3 | U4 | U5 -- U22
23      Volvo    XC90    23      1170   68   93   24   23   19    93
```

So far I have tried doing this which doesn't work (I still get both rows from the `dbo.CIS` table)

```
SELECT
 c.CarID,
 c.Make,
 c.Model,
 cis.U1,
 cis.U2,
 cis.U3,
 cis.U4,
 cis.U5
 ....
 cis.U22
FROM
 dbo.Car c
LEFT JOIN
 (SELECT
  MAX(Dist) AS Dist,
  U1, 
  U2,
  U3, 
  U4, 
  U5
  ... 
  U22
  FROM dbo.CIS
  GROUP BY
  U1, 
  U2,
  U3, 
  U4, 
  U5
  ... 
  U22
  ) AS cis
ON
 cis.CarID = c.CarID
WHERE c.CarID = 23
```

How can I return just 1 row that contains information from the `Car` table (which doesn't have duplicates by the way) and the `CIS` table which can have duplicates or no information at all for a given `CarID`. I want to return data from the `CIS` table where the `Dist` column has the highest value when there are duplicates present.

I should add that this is just a snippet from a rather larger SQL query involving many tables and joins. Hence I need whatever solution to sit within the same query rather than create temp tables separately.

Comment: Someone earlier posted a solution using OUTER APPLY which seems to have worked for me. But he's since deleted that answer not sure why.

Comment: did you end up using that `OUTER APPLY` solution? If you did, you may want to add that as an answer and accept it, if it's better than Sean's answer below.

Answer (score 9):

Here is one way to do this leveraging `ROW_NUMBER`.

```
with myCte as
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by CarID order by Dist desc) as RowNum
        , CarID
        , Dist
        , U1
        , U2
    from CIS
)

select * --Your column names here
from Car c
join myCte cis on c.CarID = cis.CarID and cis.RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses a common table expression to find the matching rows criteria for dbo.CIS table.  Then you can easily join to the `dbo.CIS` table using both the `carID` and the `Max(dist)`

```
WITH idMaxPair AS (
    SELECT carId, MAX(dist) as dist
    FROM dbo.CIS
    GROUP BY carId
)
SELECT
    c.CarID,
    c.Make,
    c.Model,
    cis.U1,
    cis.U2,
    cis.U3,
    cis.U4,
    cis.U5
    ....
    cis.U22
FROM
    dbo.Car c
LEFT JOIN idMaxPair
    ON idMaxPair.carId = c.CarID
INNER JOIN dbo.CIS cis
    ON cis.carId = idMaxPair.carId
    AND cis.dist = idMaxPair.dist
WHERE c.CarID = 23
```

Comment: This uses one `JOIN` more than Sean's solution. Using the `ROW_NUMBER` you can directly get all the fields you need from `CIS` in the `WITH` query and avoid joining that table it twice. Anyway, on a side note, there's no need to do a `LEFT JOIN` on `IdMaxPair` instead of a `INNER` one, as that table will have all `CarID`s.

Comment: @Andrew it does use one more join.  As for the `LEFT JOIN` I left it that way since the original query used a LEFT join for this table.  Thanks for the answer comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL 2012 how about using the `FIRST_VALUE` Window Function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 c.CarID,
 c.Make,
 c.Model,
 FIRST_VALUE(cis.dist) OVER (PARTITION BY cis.CarId ORDER BY CIS.Dist DESC) AS dist,
 FIRST_VALUE(cis.U1) OVER (PARTITION BY cis.CarId ORDER BY CIS.Dist DESC) AS U1,
 FIRST_VALUE(cis.U2) OVER (PARTITION BY cis.CarId ORDER BY CIS.Dist DESC) AS U2,
 FIRST_VALUE(cis.U3) OVER (PARTITION BY cis.CarId ORDER BY CIS.Dist DESC) AS U3,
 FIRST_VALUE(cis.U4) OVER (PARTITION BY cis.CarId ORDER BY CIS.Dist DESC) AS U4,
 FIRST_VALUE(cis.U5) OVER (PARTITION BY cis.CarId ORDER BY CIS.Dist DESC) AS U5,
 FIRST_VALUE(cis.U22) OVER (PARTITION BY cis.CarId ORDER BY CIS.Dist DESC) AS U22
FROM
 dbo.Car c
LEFT JOIN dbo.CIS
    ON CIS.CarId = c.CarId
WHERE c.CarID = 23
```

This results in:

```
CarID   Make    Model   dist    U1  U2  U3  U4  U5  U22
23      Volvo   XC90    1170    68  93  24  23  19  93
```

Comment: No need for the subquery here. You could just add the FIRST_VALUE to cis.dist too, then add a group by on the Car columns. I am pretty sure this would end up being slower with the extra window functions.

Comment: @SeanLange updated, haven't had chance to do any performance tests yet